# csv to dynamic html refresh

Tags: python, php, html

I have a backyard koi/goldfish pond I like to monitor.  I have a raspberry pi doing the monitoring and sending to my website.  I am trying to get the csv data to load into my index.html file.  I do not need to keep the data.  I have index 3 created the parses the data and puts in a  table.  I am having a hard time understand how to add a variable to a csv field and put that variable in the html file.

````
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<body bgcolor="000000">
<center>
<p style="color:White; font-size:50px; font-family:Couier;">Pond Temperature & Camera<br></p>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
float: left;
width: 30%;
padding: 1px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
</style>


<div class="row">
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
 <h2>Bio Falls Temperature</h2>
 <p> &deg; F</p>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
 <h2>Stream Temperature</h2>
 <p> &deg; F</p>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
 <h2>Waterfall Temperature</h2>
 <p> &deg; F</p>    
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
 <h2>Deep End Temperature</h2>
 <p> &deg; F</p>    
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
 <h2>Skimmer Temperature</h2>
 <p> &deg; F</p>    
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
 <h2>Outside Air Temperature</h2>
 <p> &deg; F</p>    
</div>
</div>


<img id="jpeg_0" width="800" height="600">

<script type="text/javascript">
 var camera_0 = {
     addEvent: function(elem, event, func ){
         if (typeof (window.event) != 'undefined')
             {elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);}
         else
             {elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);}
     },
     initCamera: function(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id, interval){
       this.addEvent(jpeg, 'load', function(){setTimeout(function() {camera_0.showJpegFrame(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id);}, interval);});
       this.showJpegFrame(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id);
     },
     showJpegFrame: function(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id){
         jpeg.src = serverUrl+"/Jpeg/"+id+"?authToken="+token+"&"+new Date().getTime();
     }
 }

camera_0.initCamera(jpeg_0, "http://100.6.115.166:8100", "4fbbf273-1691-428d-bd09-6b625aeafe0f", 0, 40);



</script>
</center>
 ```
 ```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pond Temperature & Camera</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">   
 <h1 align="center">Pond Temperature & Camera</h1>
 <br />

 <br />
 <div id="pond_table">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
url:"pond_temp.csv",
dataType:"text",
success:function(data)
{
 var pond_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
 var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
 for(var count = 0; count<pond_data.length; count++)
 {
  var cell_data = pond_data[count].split(",");
  table_data += '<tr>';
  for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
  {
   if(count === 0)
   {
    table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
   }
   else
   {
    table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
   }
  }
  table_data += '</tr>';
 }
 table_data += '</table>';
 $('#pond_table').html(table_data);
}
});
});



</script>
 ```
First probe temp is 66.4
Second probe temp is 66.2
Third probe temp is 65.4
Fourth probe temp is 66.5
Fifth probe temp is 65.5
 ```
````

Comment: Please isolate where in your big code dump we should be looking for the problem.  Chances are, we don't need to see any css declarations.  Please reduce your question to only contain relevant portions of code.  Please see [mcve].  Is this a python problem? a php problem? a javascript problem?  a **Needs More Focus** problem?

Comment: Hi maserowik, Do you have some example data that could be shown from your CSV in your question post above? Also, would it be possible to state in your question post what variable you are trying to add? :)

Comment: From the CSV file at the bottom i like to have those value be automatically added to the  www/n3bsq.com/pond.  I have the index and table already created just trying to get the temp into the location.

Comment: Hi maserowik, Would it be possible for you to provide an example line from your CSV data file? From your post information above, I can't seem to see an example of the format of your data file at the moment.

Comment: 68.9
68.8
68.9
69.3
70.1

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code some more, and looking at your post again, the code below is an attempt at helping you get to what you are trying to do, here.

Some of the main changes to note are in the HTML part where you have the "&deg F" parts. In order to let your program know where to put the temperature data in the HTML, I added some `id` tags with names that match the various temperatures.

Taking the first temperature for example, the changed HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
  <h2>Bio Falls Temperature</h2>
  <p id="bio_falls_temp"></p>
</div>
```

Another major area of change is in the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` part of your code. I've added comments throughout that section to help explain what is happening there. Basically, the code is looping through your incoming data file based on the assumption that the data looks like your data example (with an extra temperature at the end) like this:

```
68.9 68.8 68.9 69.3 70.1 80.1
```

If your data file is actually delimited with commas instead of spaces, just make sure to change this line in the example code below:

```
let pond_data_parts = pond_data[i].split(' ');
```

to this:

```
let pond_data_parts = pond_data[i].split(',');
```

The new/adjusted code loops through each line of the data file and then loops through each of the temperature data items in a row of data. If you have multiple lines of data in your data file, this code approach loops through each line and I think the last row of data in your data file is what would show up last (and then stay) in your HTML temperature "table".

Finally, another part of the new code to note is the part where the temperature data values are actually placed in the HTML temperature "table". This is especially done with the following lines of code inside of the related loops:

```
// Find element in HTML where temperature data will be placed
let item = document.querySelector('#' + pond_data_var_names[j]);
// Put temperature data in HTML along with "&deg F" part
item.innerHTML = pond_data_parts[j] + ' &deg F';
```

The actual `id` values that are selected with the `document.querySelector()` are listed earlier in the code:

```
let pond_data_var_names = [
  'bio_falls_temp',
  'stream_temp',
  'waterfall_temp',
  'deep_end_temp',
  'skimmer_temp',
  'outside_air_temp'
];
```

These are each looped through and the resulting temperature data is set in the HTML temperature "table" with this line:

```
item.innerHTML = pond_data_parts[j] + ' &deg; F';
```

If the temperatures are not showing up in the right spots in your HTML temperature "table", you might need to rearrange the order of the items in `pond_data_var_names` area. I just took a simple approach for this code example and assumed that your data values from the data file go left to right, starting at Bio Falls Temperature, then Stream Temperature, then Waterfall Temperature, then Deep End Temperature, then Skimmer Temperature, and then Outside Air Temperature.

In addition to the additions/changes I went over, I also rearranged some of your HTML so that there is a consolidated `<head></head>` section and combined some of the code from both of your example HTML files in your original post for this code. Also formatted the code in general, but you can change that if need be.

Here is what the result of my code attempt looks like based on your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  /* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1px;
  }

  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="000000">
  <center>
  <p style="color:White; font-size:50px; font-family:Couier;">Pond Temperature & Camera<br></p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
      <h2>Bio Falls Temperature</h2>
      <p id="bio_falls_temp"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
      <h2>Stream Temperature</h2>
      <p id="stream_temp"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
      <h2>Waterfall Temperature</h2>
      <p id="waterfall_temp"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
      <h2>Deep End Temperature</h2>
      <p id="deep_end_temp"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
      <h2>Skimmer Temperature</h2>
      <p id="skimmer_temp"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;">
      <h2>Outside Air Temperature</h2>
      <p id="outside_air_temp"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img id="jpeg_0" width="800" height="600">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var camera_0 = {
      addEvent: function(elem, event, func ) {
        if (typeof (window.event) != 'undefined') {
          elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
        } else {
          elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
        }
      },
      initCamera: function(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id, interval) {
        this.addEvent(jpeg, 'load', function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            camera_0.showJpegFrame(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id);
          }, interval);
        });
        this.showJpegFrame(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id);
      },
      showJpegFrame: function(jpeg, serverUrl, token, id) {
        jpeg.src = serverUrl+"/Jpeg/"+id+"?authToken="+token+"&"+new Date().getTime();
      }
    }

    camera_0.initCamera(jpeg_0, "http://100.6.115.166:8100", "4fbbf273-1691-428d-bd09-6b625aeafe0f", 0, 40);

    // These items are used later to specify where data should be put in HTML
    let pond_data_var_names = [
      'bio_falls_temp',
      'stream_temp',
      'waterfall_temp',
      'deep_end_temp',
      'skimmer_temp',
      'outside_air_temp'
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "pond_temp.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          // Split data file line by line
          let pond_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
          // Remove empty row if found
          if (pond_data[pond_data.length-1] == "") {
            pond_data.pop();
          }
          // Loop through lines from data file
          for (let i = 0; i < pond_data.length; ++i) {
            // Split up line of data using space as delimiter
            let pond_data_parts = pond_data[i].split(' ');

            // Loop through each item from line of data
            for (let j = 0; j < pond_data_parts.length; ++j) {
              // Find element in HTML where temperature data will be placed
              let item = document.querySelector('#' + pond_data_var_names[j]);
              // Put temperature data in HTML along with "&deg; F" part
              item.innerHTML = pond_data_parts[j] + ' &deg; F';
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I used a test `pond_temp.csv` file with the following data that you gave as an example (adding `80.1` at the end to fill the remaining HTML temperature "table" cell):

```
68.9 68.8 68.9 69.3 70.1 80.1
```

Here is what the output looks like on my side:

[image]

I hope this helps with your project!

---

**Update:**

In order to refresh the incoming pond data temperatures, you could potentially use [the `setInterval()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) which should run every "n" milliseconds.

If you would like to refresh the data every 5 seconds, for example, here is what the end part of the earlier code example could look like:

```
    function getPondDataAndDisplay() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "pond_temp.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          // Split data file line by line
          let pond_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
          // Remove empty row if found
          if (pond_data[pond_data.length-1] == "") {
            pond_data.pop();
          }
          // Loop through lines from data file
          for (let i = 0; i < pond_data.length; ++i) {
            // Split up line of data using space as delimiter
            let pond_data_parts = pond_data[i].split(' ');

            // Loop through each item from line of data
            for (let j = 0; j < pond_data_parts.length; ++j) {
              // Find element in HTML where temperature data will be placed
              let item = document.querySelector('#' + pond_data_var_names[j]);
              // Put temperature data in HTML along with "&deg; F" part
              item.innerHTML = pond_data_parts[j] + ' &deg; F';
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }

    // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API
    //   /WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
    let pondDataInterval = window.setInterval(getPondDataAndDisplay, 5000);
```

I took the `ajax` part of the earlier code and placed it in its own function called `getPondDataAndDisplay()`. Then, you can use `window.setInterval(getPondDataAndDisplay, 5000);` to call the new function and run it every 5 seconds.

Also, I removed the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` part that had surrounded the `ajax` part of the code, as well, for this example.

**Note:** Something to keep in mind with your incoming data file, though, is that it might get to be a large file after a while (with all the pond temperature data collected over time). It might be a good idea to make a copy of the data file on your own (saving it to another location), and then to clear out the incoming data file at some point in order to keep the file data somewhat small.

Comment: I have one more question.  I know I can add the following  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> to the code but that will refresh the whole page.  Is they a better way to issue the refresh of the table.  The camera is live streaming 24/7.

Comment: @maserowik, I've updated my earlier answer with something that might help with your additional question and have also added an additional note to consider. Hope it helps!